# Where is the log file of oom in centos?

Tags: centos

I am using centos 6.4, I find the notice as attached picture.

Then I try to find the log file in /var/log, but there's no result. Where is the log file of out of memory, i need to know what cause this problem.
[image: oom]

Comment: I guess the kernel kills the processes, so this should normally be in the kernel log.